# How to write a bash script with a for loop that creates multiple text files with different names

Tags: bash, scripting

I would like to write a simple bash script that will allow me to create 5 text files called `File1`, `File2`, `File3`, `File4` and `File5` each populated with the text "`F1`", `"F2"`, `"F3"`, `"F4"` and `"F5"` respectively.

I have tried the script

```
for i in 1,2,3,4,5; do
echo "F"$i > File$i
done
```

But this creates one file called `File1,2,3,4,5` with the text in it `F1,2,3,4,5`.

How do I correct this code?

Thank you very much

Comment: change `1,2,3,4,5` to `1 2 3 4 5` as it is being read as one string due to the IFS(internal field separator) being default(Whitespace,tab newline).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below  code to Print `F1`,`F2`,`F3`,`F4`,`F5` into five different files `File1,File2,File3,File4,File5` seperately.

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo "F"$i > File$i; done
```

- `{1..5}` Represents the range from 1 to 5.
- `do echo "F"$i > File$i` creates a file with the name as `File$i` and prints the value `F$i` to that file.(`i` represents the current value ranges from `1` to `5`).